# get list of installed packages in an enviroment conda

Tags: macos, anaconda, conda

How can I get the list of packages installed in a specific environment using conda,

I tried using `conda list` , but it shows the list of all packages.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#viewing-a-list-of-the-packages-in-an-environment):

```
conda list -n myenv
```